# No value returned from SQL update?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting no. of rows affected after running select query in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543605/getting-no-of-rows-affected-after-running-select-query-in-sql-server-2005)

How can I get the number of rows updated by an update? Something like this:

```
select update container set a = 1
```

Comment: Please read about this article from Microsoft about `@@ROWCOUNT`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
GO
```

this will show a count of the number of rows that were updated.

You can also use the ever-so-cool `@@ROWCOUNT` variable which returns that number of rows affected by the last operation.

```
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;  
GO
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @UPDATED_RECORDS int
SET @UPDATED_RECORDS = 0

select update container set a = 1

Select @UPDATED_RECORDS = @@ROWCOUNT
```

Immediately following the update statement and you should get the total number of records updated now stored in the @UPDATED_RECORDS variable.

Of course, without a filter on the update, you are updating every row in the table, so in this case SELECT COUNT(1) FROM CONTAINER should provide the same result.